# Get text inside xml tags by their name

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml.etree

I had a xml code and i want to get text in exact elements(xml tags) using python language .

I have tried couple of solutions and didnt work.

`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`
`tree = ET.fromstring(xml)`
`for node in tree.iter('Model'):`
    `print node`

How can i do that ?

**Xml Code :**

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetVehicleLimitedInfoResponse
            xmlns="http://schemas.conversesolutions.com/xsd/dmticta/v1">
            <return>
                <ResponseMessage xsi:nil="true" />
                <ErrorCode xsi:nil="true" />
                <RequestId> 2012290007705 </RequestId>
                <TransactionCharge>150</TransactionCharge>
                <VehicleNumber>GF-0176</VehicleNumber>
                <AbsoluteOwner>SIYAPATHA FINANCE PLC</AbsoluteOwner>
                <EngineNo>GA15-483936F</EngineNo>
                <ClassOfVehicle>MOTOR CAR</ClassOfVehicle>
                <Make>NISSAN</Make>
                <Model>PULSAR</Model>
                <YearOfManufacture>1998</YearOfManufacture>
                <NoOfSpecialConditions>0</NoOfSpecialConditions>
                <SpecialConditions xsi:nil="true" />
            </return>
        </GetVehicleLimitedInfoResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected output? In the code you are looking for `entry`, but there are no such elements in the XML document. Try `tree.iter()` instead.

Comment: @mzjn Example : <ClassOfVehicle>MOTOR CAR</ClassOfVehicle> I need to get the text between start and end tag  . Output must be in this case MOTOR CAR

Comment: @GHOSTH4CK3R have a look at the answer I have posted, you can use an if statement in the loop to filter out the result you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited and improved answer:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

ns = {"veh": "http://schemas.conversesolutions.com/xsd/dmticta/v1"}

tree = ET.parse('test.xml') # save your xml as test.xml
root = tree.getroot()

def get_tag_name(tag):
    return re.sub(r'\{.*\}', '',tag)

for node in root.find(".//veh:return", ns):
    print(get_tag_name(node.tag)+': ', node.text)
```

It should produce something like this:

```
ResponseMessage:  None
ErrorCode:  None
RequestId:   2012290007705 
TransactionCharge:  150
VehicleNumber:  GF-0176
AbsoluteOwner:  SIYAPATHA FINANCE PLC
EngineNo:  GA15-483936F
ClassOfVehicle:  MOTOR CAR
Make:  NISSAN
Model:  PULSAR
YearOfManufacture:  1998
NoOfSpecialConditions:  0
SpecialConditions:  None
```

Comment: I have deleted the comments where I claimed that the XML is not well namespaced. I am not an expert, and if others feel all is well, so be it.

Comment: You don't really need the function; just change the last line to `print(node.tag.split('}')[1],": ",node.text)`.