# How to extract Integer from XMl file with Python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, visual-studio

I'm working on a project using Python3 on LinuxMint

I have a directory with subdirectrories that contain 100+ XML files. Each XML file has an event ID line like the following:

```
<EventID Qualifiers="">1102</EventID>
```

How would I go about writing some code that reads the files and extracts only the number within the >< (in this case 1102) and prints it to the terminal (in VisualStudioCode which I am using)? I have tried using regex with strings and patterns but to no avail. Usually resulting in errors
I'm fairly new to Python and SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65492653/14739759

Comment: No. it does not answer my question.They are extracting from a website link, I need to extract the information from files in several subdirectories. As mentioned in the main question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils

ids = []
path = 'xmlpath/'
files = utils.getSubFile(path, end='.xml')
for f in files:
  xml = utils.getFileContent(f)
  doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
  id = doc.select('EventID>text()')
  ids.append(id)

print (ids)
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: This is the one! Thank you so much :D

Comment: Would I be able to modify that so  a print statement or something is on the end of that code that says something like "there were (number of returned values) IDs"?

Comment: I'm not sure which variable to use to show that?

Comment: @NewBlock121 I updated the answer, I don't know if it's what you want